# What's the best way to add project level metadata to a google cloud project?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Labels are project level have character limitations like cannot have spaces. I could add metadata through a bigquery table, or on each server. I could also make a  README.txt on the default appspot bucket.

What's the best way to add metadata at a project level? Things like what the project is about, why it's there, people responsible, stakeholders, developers, context/vocabulary. Eg when I get fired people can see what is what.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Storing Metadata:**

**1. Console**

This is quite straightforward. Once you navigate to **Metadata** section under **Compute Engine** (Compute Engine > Metadata), you can add project-level key:value pair in the console.

**2. gcloud**

Type the following command in the cloud shell of the project.

```
gcloud compute project-info add-metadata --metadata projectMailID=abc@gmail.com
```

**3. API**

Sending a post request to the google API. This is usually a more manual task, where you need to make a GET first to get fingerprint and then post to the API using the fingerprint.

**Querying Metadata:**

**1. curl or wget**

This is the frequently used option for getting instance or project metadata.

```
curl "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/project/" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"
```

The above command will list all the metadata associated with the given project. Metadata can be stored either in **directory** or a **single entry**. If the **URL** ends in **/**, then it lists the directory, else it shows the value of single entry key.

The custom-metadata are stored under attributes directory. This can be retrieved by:

```
curl "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/project/attributes/" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"
```

The above command lists all custom entries made in the project. To get the value of a single entry, try this:

```
curl "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/project/attributes/ProjectMailID" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"
```

**Metadata-Flavor: Google**

This header indicates that the request was sent with the intention of retrieving metadata values, rather than unintentionally purposes.

**2. gcloud**

The gcloud command will list all metadata and other information about the project.

```
gcloud compute project-info describe
```

**3. API**

Making a GET request to the API will do the equivalent of gcloud.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/<project>
```

**Additional Information:**

**Waiting For Updates**

This option allows to wait for any changes to the metadata and then retrieve the updated value. This can be done by appending **?wait_for_change=true** as query parameter.

```
curl "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/project/attributes/?wait_for_change=true" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"
```

**Recursive**

This option is used to print recursively the entries in the directory. This can be done by appending **?recursive=true** as query parameter.

```
curl "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/project/attributes/?recursive=true" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"
```